# Caffeine LoadingCache - Eviction with Custom expiration policy

Tags: java, caching, guava, caffeine-cache

Using [Caffeine 2.8.1](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/2.8.1/index.html) and Java 8.
I have created `LoadingCache<String, Boolean>`. I am loading the cache with `cache.putAll(getAllKeyValues())` where `getAllKeyValues()` returns a `Map<String, Boolean>`.

I have specified a *CacheLoader* to compute the value by calling `keyExistsOnServer(key)` method which calls an external service to get the value.

I have specified a Custom expiration policy where I want to evict the entry from cache in 10 minutes if the value is set as `false` while **creating/updating** the entry in the cache. And keep it as long as `Long.MAX_VALUE` if the value is `true`.

```
  private RemovalListener<String, Boolean> removeListener =
      (key, value, cause) ->
          logger.info(
              "Entry for Key={} with value={} was removed ({}) from cache", key, value, cause);
  private LoadingCache<String, Boolean> cache =
      Caffeine.newBuilder()
          .expireAfter(
              new Expiry<String, Boolean>() {
                private static final long EXPIRATION_TEN_MINS_IN_NANOSECONDS = 600000000000L;

                @Override
                public long expireAfterCreate(String key, Boolean value, long currentTime) {
                  // If value is false that means key does not exist, so set expiration to 10 mins
                  return value ? Long.MAX_VALUE : EXPIRATION_TEN_MINS_IN_NANOSECONDS;
                }

                @Override
                public long expireAfterUpdate(
                    String key, Boolean value, long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
                  // If value is changed from true to false then set expiration to 10 mins
                  return value ? Long.MAX_VALUE : EXPIRATION_TEN_MINS_IN_NANOSECONDS;
                }

                @Override
                public long expireAfterRead(
                    String key, Boolean value, long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
                  // Don't modify expiration time after read
                  return currentDuration;
                }
              })
          .recordStats()
          .removalListener(removeListener)
          .build(key -> keyExistsOnServer(key));
```

---

**Question#1:** Does my expiration policy looks correct based on what I want to achieve?

**Question#2:**

I do not see the `RemovalListener` getting called as per the eviction policy. This may be due the accrual of tasks for cleanup as stated in this [github issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2110).

However, correctness of my code relies on the fact that once the expiration duration (10 minutes in case of `false` value) have passed for an entry and if we call `cache.get(key)` then it should not return the expired value from cache, but rather call the `CacheLoader` i.e. *keyExistsOnServer(key)* method to get the value. Can someone assert that this is how it will behave?

Here is what @Louis Wasserman has stated on the github issue but I not clear if this clarifies it:

> Actually, what happens is that the get call itself discovers that the entry is expired and adds it to the queue of entries to be cleaned up

**Question#3:** What happens if there is `RuntimeException` thrown by `CacheLoader` that is *keyExistsOnServer(key)* method on calling `cache.get(key)`?

**Question#4**: Would `cache.asMap()` contain the entries which are expired but were not evicted due to accrual for cleanup?

**Question#5**: When I am logging the `currentDuration` in the `expireAfterRead()` method, it does not seem consistent with the elapsed time. i.e. if it was set to *600000000000* (10 mins) with an update for the value to `false` I am expecting that after 5 mins it should be *300000000000* but it was not. Why so?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Could you please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question#1: Does my expiration policy looks correct based on what I want to achieve?

Yes, this looks good. You might make your constant a `Duration` or use `TimeUnit` for the calculation, just to make it look prettier.

> Question#2: I do not see the RemovalListener getting called as per the eviction policy.

This will occur when enough activity on the cache occurs. You can specify a `Scheduler` which will wake up and call `cache.cleanUp` for you, based on when the next entry is set to expire. For Java 9+ users, Java offers a built-in scheduling thread that you can leverage by adding `Caffeine.scheduler(Scheduler.systemScheduler)` when constructing the cache.

> Once the expiration duration has passed for an entry and if we call cache.get(key) then it should not return the expired value from cache, but rather call the CacheLoader.

Correct. The cache will validate the entry on lookup and, if expired, load it anew. It will never return an expired entry.

> Question#3: What happens if there is RuntimeException thrown by CacheLoader that is keyExistsOnServer(key) method on calling cache.get(key)?

The mapping will not be established and the exception will propagate to the caller. The next call to `get(key)` will try anew, which might fail again. It is your choice of how to be resilient towards this. Often not being so is a good answer, or sometimes caching that it failed is a better one.

> Question#4: Would cache.asMap() contain the entries which are expired but were not evicted due to accrual for cleanup?

The cache will hold the entries but suppress them from being visible, e.g. by lookup or iteration. The only external indication is that `size()` since that counter is not updated until the expired entry is removed.

> Question#5: When I am logging the currentDuration in the expireAfterRead() method, it does not seem consistent with the elapsed time. i.e. if it was set to 600000000000 (10 mins) with an update for the value to false I am expecting that after 5 mins it should be 300000000000 but it was not. Why so?

Please open an issue with a unit test and we can diagnose.

Comment: Thanks Ben, For Q#2 Will the `cache.get(key)` call CacheLoader, for the entry that expired but not evicted? documentation says `It will never be visible to read or write operations`, can you pls confirm. Any thoughts on Q#4 and Q#5?

Comment: Updated, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, this is really helpful. I do see some weird behavior though, For a key if I do a `get(k)` call, so the key/value should be cached after that and I see the log from `expireAfterCreate()` method too. Now, I expect the subsequent call for that key to be returned from the cache. However, the 2nd `get(k)` call also invoke `CacheLoader` to get the value. The 3rd `get(k)` works as expected and get the value from cache itself. Wondering why this behavior, Are the cache entry creations also accrued? and then performed later?

Comment: Nevermind, I have 2 instances of the application running. So, 2nd call might have gone to the other instance that might be the case. I will check that. Thank you

Comment: @BenManes How to user a scheduler to evict the expired cache entries?  Do we need to pass a scheduled when building a Caffeine? `@Bean
    public Cache<String, Oauth2Token> oauth2Cache(){
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .initialCapacity(100)
                .maximumSize(1000)
                .expireAfter(new CustomExpiryForOauth())
                .scheduler(Caffeine.scheduler("4000")  ## this is not working
                .build();
    }`

Comment: @Arvind Use the static methods on the interface, e.g. `Scheduler.systemScheduler()`, and pass it into the builder.